# Help with a Proof of an Inequality Involving a Difference

Tags: calculus, number-theory, inequality

I have this inequality: $$(\left(e^Yx\ln\left(\ln\left(e^Yx\right)\right)+\ln\left(e^Yx\right)\right))-\left(e^Yx\ln\left(\ln\left(x\right)\right)+\frac{0.1209x}{\ln\left(\ln\left(x\right)\right)^2}\right) > 0$$ where $x>5$ and $Y$ is Euler's constant ($0.5772...$) I numerically checked that it's true, but I have no idea how to start to prove that it's true. I was hoping someone could help me.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @saulspatz I tried proving that $$\left(e^Yx\ln\left(\ln\left(e^Yx\right)\right)\right)-\left(e^Yx\ln\left(\ln\left(x\right)\right)\right)$$ is greater than $$\ln\left(e^Yx\right)-\frac{0.1209x}{\ln\left(\ln\left(x\right)\right)^2}$$ but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$e^\gamma x\log\log e^\gamma x-e^\gamma x\log\log x=e^\gamma x\log(\gamma +\log x)-e^\gamma x\log\log x=e^\gamma x\cdot\gamma\frac{1}{\theta+\log x}\leq e^\gamma x\cdot\gamma\frac{1}{\log x},$$
where the second equality follows from the mean value theorem, where $0\leq\theta\leq\gamma$.

Therefore the left-hand side of your inequality is a sum of a term which is $O(x/\log x)$ and a term which is $O(\log x)$, minus a term which is asymptotically $x/(\log\log x)^2$. Since $(\log\log x)^2$ grows asymptotically slower than $\log x$, this last term eventually dominates and we get that your inequality is *false* for large enough $x$.

How large, you may ask? Well, ignoring the $\log e^\gamma$ term, the inequality only reverses around $10^{262}$ ([Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5Egamma*+%28log+log+x%29%5E2+%3C0.1209+log+x)), so even with that term probably somewhere there.

Comment: Great answer, though your link doesn't show your claim of $10^{262}$